# How to recode multiple columns in a table based on another table [R or Python]?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

My data frame has several columns with string values that I want to recode as integers. **There are over 20 columns**, each with its unique key-value pairs (and **not all have to be recoded**), so I'm looking for a way to avoid writing 20+ case_when's, with anywhere between 3-6 cases each (which is what the 3+ answers I read so far suggest).

I have the string-integer pairs in a different table, I'm wondering if there's a way to iterate through the columns of data and the rows of the key-value pairs, to recode the strings, like so:

Data:

```
C1 C2 C3
A  D  X
B  E  Y
C  F  Z
```

Key-value pairs:

```
Column_name  String   Int
C2           D        5
C2           E        10
C2           F        0
C3           X        1
C3           Y        2
C3           Z        7
```

Output:

```
C1  C2  C3
A   5   1
B   10  2
C   0   7
```

In other words, for every data column C#, the code will look only at the key-value rows for C#, and replace the strings with their values.

I'm open to an R or Python solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dplyr `left_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


data %>% 
    gather(Column_name, String, -C1) %>% 
    left_join(key_vals) %>% 
    select(-String) %>% 
    spread(Column_name, Int)

#### OUTPUT ####

  C1 C2 C3
1  A  5  1
2  B 10  2
3  C  0  7
```

This method can be scaled by excluding more variables from `gather`. For example, with the following dataframe:

```r
data <- bind_cols(data, data)

#### OUTPUT ####

  C1 C2 C3 C11 C21 C31
1  A  D  X   A   D   X
2  B  E  Y   B   E   Y
3  C  F  Z   C   F   Z
```

If we don't want to recode C11-C31 we can subtract them from `gather`. You'll also need to specify the variables you want to join on in `left_join` (wasn't necessary above because they were the only possibilities):

```r
data %>% 
    gather(Column_name, String, -c(C1, C11:C31)) %>% 
    left_join(key_vals, by = c("Column_name", "String")) %>% 
    select(-String) %>% 
    spread(Column_name, Int)

#### OUTPUT ####

  C1 C11 C21 C31 C2 C3
1  A   A   D   X  5  1
2  B   B   E   Y 10  2
3  C   C   F   Z  0  7
```

It changes the order a little, but I think the result is what you're looking for.

Comment: Would this approach scale to an arbitrary number of columns, not all of which have to be recoded?

Comment: @Khashir yes, I believe so if you include those columns in the initial `gather`.

Comment: @Khashir I've added an example to my answer where some variables are not recoded.

Comment: None of the solutions worked out of the box (probably an issue with the actual data); but the logic of this one helped me get to a solution. Hence, I picked this one as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way from `pandas`

```
d={x : y.set_index('String').Int.to_dict() for x , y in pairs.groupby('Column_name')}
Data.replace(d)
Out[611]: 
  C1  C2  C3
0  A   5   1
1  B  10   2
2  C   0   7
```

In R with `merge` and `rehsape2`

```
df1$id=1:dim(df1)[1]
s=merge(melt(df1,'id'),pairs,by.x=c('variable','value'),by.y=c('Column_name','String'),all.x=T)
s$Int[is.na(s$Int)]=s$value[is.na(s$Int)]

dcast(data = s, formula = id ~ variable, value.var = "Int")
  id C1 C2 C3
1  1  A  5  1
2  2  B 10  2
3  3  C  0  7
```

Comment: It is possible that a value in `'String'` repeats in a different `'Column_name'` group.  Use this `df.replace({k: dict(zip(d.String, d.Int)) for k, d in pairs.groupby('Column_name')})`

Comment: @piRSquared yep , notice that too, and just update :-), thank you sir

Comment: That was crazy fast—and in both languages! You, sir or madam, just blew my mind—amazing.

Comment: @Khashir yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Another way to create the dictionary

```
d = {}
for c, s, i in zip(*map(pairs.get, pairs)):
    d.setdefault(c, {})[s] = i

df.replace(d)

  C1  C2  C3
0  A   5   1
1  B  10   2
2  C   0   7
```

Comment: Wow, so succinct. Will this scale to an arbitrary number of column, not all of which have to be recoded?

Comment: Yes it will.  It tells `replace` to only replace on the columns specified by the dictionary.  Mind that WeNYoBen's answer does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

With `R` we can do this without any packages (in `base R`) using a named vector

```
df1[-1] <- Map(function(x, y) y[x], df1[-1], 
          with(df2, split(setNames(Int, String), Column_name)))

df1
#  C1 C2 C3
#1  A  5  1
#2  B 10  2
#3  C  0  7
```

---

Also, if the columns are ordered, then this is much more compact

```
df1[-1] <-  with(df2, setNames(Int, String))[as.matrix(df1[-1])]
```

and without any whitespaces (#save_space)

```
df1[-1]<-with(df2,setNames(Int,String))[as.matrix(df1[-1])]
```

NOTE: This can get scaled to any number of columns

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(C1 = c("A", "B", "C"), C2 = c("D", "E", "F"), 
    C3 = c("X", "Y", "Z")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Column_name = c("C2", "C2", "C2", "C3", "C3", 
"C3"), String = c("D", "E", "F", "X", "Y", "Z"), Int = c(5L, 
10L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```